# Merge count and row in pandas data frame if value in column matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas data frame like the following:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John', 'David', 'John', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Tim'], 'count' : [4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1]})
```

How can I make a new data frame which merges the count values (adds) based on the values in the name column?

The final result for this example should be:

```
   count   name
0      7   John
1      5  David
2      4    Bob
3      1    Tim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `sum()` on that

```
In [276]: test.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
Out[276]:
    name  count
0    Bob      4
1  David      5
2   John      7
3    Tim      1
```